# Why is the .click() handler not firing on my button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had no problems getting my .click handlers to fire elsewhere on my page. For some reason, I can't seem to figure out why my handler isn't firing for a jQuery button .click event. I've trawled through so many other questions posted here, but I haven't had any luck.

The first part of the code gets the button element and calls the .click function on it. I've also changed the text of the button to prove that I'm selecting the right element.

```
var removeButton = $("friend_remove_button");
removeButton.text("remove");
removeButton.click( function(eventObject)
{ 
    removeFriendFromList(eventObject); 
});
```

The second part of the code is the removeFriendFromList function. This has more stuff happening in my project, but I can't even get it to display an alert, as seen here. Once I can get that going, I should have not problem.

```
function removeFriendFromList(eventObject)
{
        alert("Button Clicked!");
        selectedId = $(eventObject.currentTarget).attr('id');
}
```

You can find a jsFiddle of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/YLNkE/1/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you missed something,try var removeButton = $(".friend_remove_button");

Comment: more like `var removeButton = $(".friend_remove_button");`

Comment: God, that was stupid. I'm embarrassed. Safe to say I'll never make that mistake again. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var removeButton = $(".friend_remove_button");
```

You are missing the `.` in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the class selectors in jQuery/CSS

```
var removeButton = $(".friend_remove_button");
```

**Note:**

`.` is for class selectors and `#` is for Id selector and for standadard HTML controls take names directly like `input`, `button`, `select` .. etc. not custom buttons.

[**<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLNkE/6/)